# problemas con dataset y reportviewer (mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, reportviewer

Hola a todos buenas noches, estoy comenzando con los reportes en un pequeño sistema en c# y mysql, agrego un dataset y cuando quiero utilizar el procedimiento almacenado me muestra este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si intento con una tabla, pasa lo mismo, crea el tableadapater vacio.

he usado los conectores de mysql, he creado odbc de 32 y 64 bits y aun asi nada...

Saludos a todos y gracias por sus comentarios

Comment: Creo (no recuerdo muy bien) que esta consulta realiza una llamada con todos los parametros NULL y debe devolver un conjunto de datos (vacio puede ser pero no debe dar error). Fijate si es algo de esto que te estoy comentando. Si no es asi, te pediria que coloques mas info de como lo haces paso a paso a la registracion de conjunto de datos asi lo podemos reproducir

Comment: Por favor [edit] y agrege el `SELECT` o el `spMostrarBoxes`= ¿tiene parámetros?, ¿el wizard comprobó si pudo realizar la conexión a la base de datos?